# Is it possible to view revisions suggested by me?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

Today I have suggested a revision to another user's answer that seemed to have been rejected. Since I considerer it valuable, I would like recover it and publish it as my own answer.

Is there a way to access my suggested revision?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is very simple.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

You can also just navigate to your profile page, select the "Activity" tab, and under "All actions" select "suggested edits".
It also has a column "revisions", but that only shows edits that came through — either because they were approved or because they were made on a post that didn't need review. (Your own posts, or edits you make after you gain full edit privileges).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Marked as best answer because it explains navigation and contains the link.

Answer (score 9):

There's a way to get to the review of your post, which can *also* enlighten you as to why it was rejected. Go to your profile and click the "all actions" tab.

[image]

In that tab, you'll find more tabs. To get to all your suggested edits, you want "suggestions".

[image]

From here, click the "rejected edit" or "approved edit" text to get to the finished review. You can also view still pending edits this way, which will be labelled as such.

[image]

You can use this in the future to review your suggested edits, which will help you learn what is and is not acceptable as an edit, at least for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378115/julio-nobre?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Comment: @les No, it's not a link only answer.  It answers the question even if you don't follow the link.